# Database and Server solutions for a multiroom application in ReactJS

Tags: node.js, reactjs, database, websocket, socket.io

## Context

I am working on a React webapp which has to do the following :

1. Users access to a webpage using one common URL (about 10 thousands users max)
2. There's a second URL for "admins".
3. Each admin can create a "room" and transmit the room ID to some users (max 40 user per room). The room will be open for 2h max.
4. Once users access the room, they can transmit infos by clicking on a button (like Task 1 done by clicking on a button next to Task 1)

I'm thinking also about adding a chat where users can chat with the admin of the room.

This webapp will be hosted on an Apache server which has already other apps in it.

## Issue / Solutions ?

I'm trying to figure out which tools (database, websocket) I should use for this project and I would like some feedback considering the relevance of my initial plan (and suggestions for improvements).

- Server : using node.js and the ws library (I'd like to avoid socket.io which seems a bit heavy) I can handle the communication between users and admin. From what I remember I will have to do some configuration on the Apache server for node.js to work.
- Database : Unfortunately I can't use databases like Firebase and I was thinking about using a database which I'm already using on my server (MariaDB) to create a database for each room, storing which task was done by which user, and also the messages sent from a user to an admin. But I've seen a tutorial on how to make a Chat Application in React, which was using LocalStorage instead of a database.
- Safety : I'd say that this kind of app can have serious safety issue, but have no idea if some tools can prevent the most common attacks...

## Conclusion

So, all in all, I'm thinking about using ReactJS + node.js + ws library + LocalStorage instead of a DB, all of this on an Apache Server. Does it seems like a mildly convenient solution for this project.

I realize that my question is a bit far fetched, but I don't have the experience to know the tools for such a project.

Thanking you all in advance.